# PostgreSQL 9.5.2 - Building a JSON object/String - Multiple 1:many relationships

Tags: mysql, json, postgresql

I am playing with PostgreSQL building JSON objects/strings for a project.

I am new with the syntax and am looking for "best practices" in doing this.

Imagine the following tables (ignoring the design)

```
CREATE TABLE object (
    item_id INT
    ,name VARCHAR(64)
    ,category_id INT
)
CREATE TABLE object_features (
    item_id INT
    ,feature_1 VARCHAR(64)
    ,val_1 FLOAT
    ,feature_2 VARCHAR(64)
    ,val_2 FLOAT
    ,feature_3 VARCHAR(64)
    ,val_3 FLOAT
    ,feature_n VARCHAR(64)
    ,val_n FLOAT
)
CREATE TABLE category (
    id INT
    ,name VARCHAR(64)
)
CREATE TABLE comment (
    object_id  INT
    ,name VARCHAR(64)
    ,date DATETIME
    ,score INT
)
```

How would you create the following JSON (or at least as close as possible)?

```
[{
    "item_id": 1234,
    "category": "category 1",
    "name": "xyz",
    "features": [{
        "feature_1": "val_1",
        "highlight": "Y"
    }, {
        "feature_4": "val_2",
        "highlight": "Y"
    }, {
        "feature_3": "val_3",
        "highlight": "N"
    }, {
        "feature_n": "val_n",
        "highlight": "Y"
    }],
    "comments": [{
        "name": "larry",
        "date": "2016-04-01",
        "score": 1
    }, {
        "name": "harry",
        "date": "2016-03-01",
        "score": 5
    }]
}, {
    "item_id": 434,
    "category": "category 2",
    "name": "dda",
    "features": [{
        "feature_1": "val_1",
        "highlight": "N"
    }, {
        "feature_4": "val_2",
        "highlight": "N"
    }, {
        "feature_3": "val_3",
        "highlight": "N"
    }, {
        "feature_n": "val_n",
        "highlight": "N"
    }],
    "comments": [{
        "name": "merry",
        "date": "2016-04-01",
        "score": 1
    }]
}]
```

Regards,
G